# What's the difference between project references and project dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I have a simple solution in Visual Studio 2010 containing a few static libraries, a few DLLs, and an executable.

Some libraries depend one another (for example the DLL needs two static lib projects to be built before building the DLL itself), and it seems there are two way to achieve this:

1) If I right click on the solution I can select "Project dependencies..." and set the build order

2) I can right click on the DLL project and select Properties->Framework and References and then add a new reference.

What is the difference between #1 and #2? What is the better way to express a build dependency between two projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I recommend to use Add Project Reference to the project and let Visual Studio figure out the build order. Usually there should be no need to manually edit the build order.

Comment: Yes my colleagues here told me the same thing. I'm just curious about the difference

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only difference between a "Project Reference Definition" and a "Project Dependency Definition" is the metadata that defines the output assembly inclusion/exclusion into/from the main project link command.

In Visual Studio 2010-and-going-forward, Microsoft wants you to start using the "Framework and References" dialog, and stop using the "Project Dependencies" dialog (for now, the "Project Dependencies" dialog remains, will probably be removed in the future).

Here's a blog entry that talks about this, and other "Project settings changes with VS2010" by one of the Visual Studio developers:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/project-settings-changes-with-vs2010/

Comment: I occasionally encounter a bug in VS2013 where a project dependency does not create a build dependency.  This seems to be the case for a project that is excluded from the build in Release but not Debug.  It is inconsistent and aggravating, but manually adding the build dependency fixes it.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2015, the References are no longer in the property sheet, but now below the project in the tree in Project Explorer.

Comment: Upon adding a reference (via Solution Explorer > References), Visual Studio automatically adds the referenced project as a project dependency which cannot be removed until the reference is removed.