# Visual Studio 2010 project references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, solution

In my project we have some references defined to a subproject. I have some problems with that, because I'm not sure what thhis reference is supposed to be. Normally I would have created abuild dependency between the two libraries/applications. I think that this project reference is supposed to replace that. I found this posting here ([What's the difference between project references and project dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259128/whats-the-difference-between-project-references-and-project-dependencies)) but somehow I don't get it (also read the link to MSDN included).

The issue I have is, that when I work with this project everything is fine. When a collegue downloads the solution from the repository it complains about `The project file '' has been renamed or is no longer in this project`. Now he has to redefine the references to the forementioned subproject (a library). But this is not really a solution, because when this supposed fixed reference is checked in, then the next guy checking it out, has the same problem again. It works only on the machine that the project was redefined.

The issue seems to be that there is an UUID associated with a project, and the reference is using that. On another machine this UUID seems to be wrong/missing, so it has to be redefined. Not sure whats going on or how to resolve that.

Comment: Maybe something's broken in Solution. I suggest to create a new solution with all the projects and the dependencies in, and try this.

Comment: Yes, I already did that for myself, but the problem is that this a companies project, so I can not simply create a new one. :) Rather I have to find the problem and fix it, so that others can continue with this solution.

Comment: It's not possible to update this company project to the new one? You could  try to compare the two .sln files into a text editor...

Comment: Currently I'm trying that approach. I had hoped that there would be some obvious "you have to change this file/entry" solution that I may have missed. :) Problem is that there are so many subprojects and some of them outdated and not compilable, so it's a real mess.